# JSON data not returning properly from Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, json

In this HTML code, when the input field called "nu_protocolo" looses focus the Ajax code calls the php script *ajax.getting_data.php*

**HTML Code:**

*form.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript">      

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#nu_protocolo").focusout(function() {
            var dados = 'protocolo=' + $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type:           'POST',
                dataType:       'text',
                async:          true,
                url:            'ajax.getting_data.php',
                data:           dados,
                success: function (response) {                        
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<!-- Form Content  -->
<div id="content">
    <form id="form_requisicao" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group mostra_protocolo">
            <label for="nu_protocolo" class="control-label col-md-4">Número Protocolo:</label> 
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" id="nu_protocolo" name="nu_protocolo" placeholder="Número Protocolo" type="text" class="form-control input-protocolo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**PHP Code:**

ajax.getting_data.php

```
    <?php
    ...
    ...

    $empregados = 
        array(
            'quantidade'                    => $qt_estagiarios,
            'protocolo_ano'                 => $estagiario_prot_ano,
            'protocolo_origem'              => $estagiario_prot_origem,
            'protocolo_numero'              => $estagiario_prot_numero

        );

    $rs = json_encode($empregados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo $rs;
```

The output from the PHP code is:

**JSON Data:**

```
    {
    "quantidade": "2",
    "protocolo_ano": "25",
    "protocolo_origem": "40",
    "protocolo_numero": "65000"
    }
```

Displaying the console data in the HTML code you get the same JSON data as you hardcode the PHP code. The problem is when you specify a variable like "quantidade". Gives me the *undefined* value displayed on the console.
I tried many ways to specify the variable but didn´t get any result:

*form.html*

```
       ...
       ...
            success: function (response) {                        
                console.log(response.quantidade);
                console.log(response[0].quantidade);
                console.log(response[0]);
            }
       ...
       ...
```

Comment: What do you have on `console.log(response);`?

Comment: The JSON Data displayed above..

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `dataType: 'text',` to `dataType: 'json',` in your `$.ajax({...})` call because it defines response preprocessing type http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#data-types

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure jQuery is treating your JSON as JSON.

By default, PHP claims it outputs HTML, so you need:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

… to say that you are sending JSON.

---

Then you have this:

> ```
> dataType:       'text',
> ```

… which tells jQuery to ignore the Content-Type header and treat the response as plain text.

So remove that (or change it to `dataType: 'json'` to tell jQuery to ignore the Content-Type and treat the response as JSON.

Comment: The problem is only in `dataType: 'text',`. jQuery processes response correctly even without proper header if we have proper `dataType` provided

Comment: If we provide proper header from backend. we can omit `dataType` property on `$.ajax()` call

Comment: @PavloZhukov — As I said, `dataType` causes jQuery to ignore the content-type header. That doesn't mean you should still send the wrong one.

Comment: My former client nearly never send it in project more the 4 years old and few GBs together with `.git` directory. But I agree that it is a bad practice